# Decode and extract profile ID from the url

Tags: python, encoding

I am trying to scrape the following page:

> https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/22241746/7192z-boul-henri-bourassa-o-montr%C3%A9al-saint-laurent-new-saint-laurentbois-franc#view=neighbourhood

The page is using a third party application generate the neighbourhood ratings and below is the call it makes

> https://api.locallogic.co/v1/scores/bG9jYWxsb2dpYweyJ0b2tlbiI6ImI3NTA1YjRkYjNlMjM1Y2IxYTA0MzBmYjAwMzhlOGRhOTdiMzI1N2E2Mzc2YTUwODVhMmRmZWQ3OTExZmZkZmQzODE2NGVhYjBiOTczNDBkIiwibGF0IjoiNDUuN***TA4NjU2MzgiLCJsbmciOiItNzMuNzM0OTA1MzUifQ==***

The highlighted part in the above call encode the following profile (Id or Some other characteristic)

```
Profile : 22241746/7192z-boul-henri-bourassa-o-montr%C3%A9al-saint-laurent-new-saint-laurentbois-franc

MLS Number : 9104133
```

I am not able to understand how may have been encoded but know that the Long Lat are required by this API, Would really appreciate if someone can help

PS: I do not want the API key as I will be using my own

Comment: It seems to be base64 encoding, but when decoding it I get some binary interspersed with ASCII characters, and it doesn't fully decode correctly: `locallogic�'F��V�#�&#sSV#FF#6S#3V6#C3f#3�S�F�v#3#Svc3sfS�V&FfVCs�ffFfC3�cFV##�s3CB"�&�B#�#CR�S�cSc3�"�&��r#�"�s2�s3C�S3R'�base64: invalid input`

Comment: But instead of trying to reverse engineer this, why not just [read the documentation](https://docs.locallogic.co/api-endpoints/location-scores#querystring-request-parameters)?

Comment: Hey Thomas, Thanks for cheking
I need to know the long lat of the property to make the API call, but I dont have the cordinates, So wondering of I can decode how and in what form are those stored for a particular property

Answer (score 0):

Resolved,

when used base64 decoder, I got
locallogic�'F��V�#�&#sSV#FF#6S#3V6#C3f#3�S�F�v#3#Svc3sfS�V&FfVCs�ffFfC3�cFV##�s3CB"�&�B#�#CR�S�cSc3�"�&��r#�"�s2�s3C�S3R'�

from the input I removed the code that decodes to locallogic and voila

Remaining code when decoded returns a perfect dictionary